# How to handle On Exception in the base controller of asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0hON.png)I am new to development and I am working on a project to convert the asp.net application to asp.net core. 
But I am facing a few challenges on the on exception method. 
I need your assistance and guidance for this cause. 
The on exception error is thrown as there is not suitable method found over ride. 
Below is my code.

```js
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var urlReferrerAbsolutePath = HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();

            var canvasName = urlReferrerAbsolutePath.Split('-').Last();
            canvasName = canvasName.Replace("%20", " ");

            ec_log log = new ec_log()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                ControllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
                ActionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
                Type = Share.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR,
                LogginOn = Share.MESSAGE_TYPE_EXCEPTION,
                LoggedInUserId = LoggedInId,
                LoggedInUserName = Share.LoggedInMembersFirstName,
                Exception = (filterContext.Exception.InnerException != null ?
                                 filterContext.Exception.InnerException.ToString()
                                 : "") + " " + filterContext.Exception.Message,
                System = _systemName,
                CompanyID = Share.LoggedInMembersCompanyID,
                Url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl(),
                CanvasName = canvasName,
                StackTrace = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace != null ? filterContext.Exception.StackTrace : ""
            };
            new LogModel(_configuration).InsertLog(log);
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                return;
            }
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx"
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj6nr.png)

Comment: Suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your guidance my friends. 
Hope the solution will be helpful for you as well.

```js
public virtual void OnException (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ExceptionContext filtercontext);
```

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is because the parent class does not define the method called `OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)`

You can see this from the documentation that changing from the MVC (.NET Framework) `Controller` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) the class contains the method but for .NET Core `Controller` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-3.1) no such method is defined.

In order to have similar functionality in .Net Core, consider moving the OnException logic above into an `ExceptionFilter` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters)